# How do nested scopes affect stack depth?

Tags: c, assembly, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

I tried compiling the following c-code using MSVC into assembly both with (CL TestFile.c /Fa /Ot) and without optimizations (CL TestFile.c /Fa) and the result is they produce the same stack-depth.

Why does the compiler use 8 bytes for each of the 3 varibles x, y, and z when it knows it will use a maximum of 16 bytes? Instead of `y$1 = 4` and `z$2 = 8` could it not use `y$1 = 4` and `z$2 = 4` so `y` and `z` use the same memory on the stack without any problems?

```c
int main() {
  int x = 123;
  if (x == 123) {
    int y = 321;
  }
  else {
    int z = 234;
  }
}
```

```
; Parts of the assembly code
x$ = 0
y$1 = 4
z$2 = 8
main PROC
$LN5:
  sub rsp, 24
; And so on...
```

Comment: I now tried compiling using: CL TestFile.c /Fa /Ot so it will optimize, yet the output is the same. The compiler does not seem to optimize this.

Comment: I expect this program to compile into a single return instruction with full optimizations, as it does nothing.

Comment: @EugeneSh. volatile and they should not be optimized out

Comment: @0___________ Volatile might have some other effects I guess... Because this question is about certain optimizations anyway

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/rWshrv

Comment: I've never studied the issue, but I've gotten the pretty strong impression that most compilers simply do not try very hard to overlap the local variables in nonoverlapping inner blocks.  So while writing code that does this *might* save you stack space, there's no guarantee that it *will*.

Comment: @SteveSummit they do not. I do not know any which actually do. When optimizing the program flow does not have to be as the one in your program.

Comment: Try `/O1` or `/O2` or `/Ox`.

Comment: I don't think `/Os` or `/Ot` enable optimization by themselves, at least for recent MSVC. Look for "`; Function compile flags:`" in the assembler output for the optimization flags used. With `/Ot` on its own, I get "`; Function compile flags: /Odtp`" and the `d` means optimization is disabled. (I've no idea what the `p` means.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested scopes do not affect stack depth. Per the C standard, nested scopes affect visibility of identifiers and do not impose any requirements on how a C implementation uses the stack, if it has one. A C compiler is permitted by the C standard generate any code that gets the same observable behavior.

For the program shown in the question, the only observable behavior is to exit with a success status, so a good compiler should, when optimizing, generate a minimal program. For example, [GCC 10.2 for x86-64 generates just an `xor` and a `ret`](https://godbolt.org/z/vGjv8Y):

```
main:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

So does Clang 11.0.1. If MSVC does not, that is a deficiency in it. (However, it may be that the switches `/Os` and `/Ot` do not request optimization or do not request much optimization; they may just express a preference for speed or time when used in conjunction with other optimization switches.)

Further, a good compiler should perform lifetime analysis of the use of objects, constructing a graph representing where nodes are places in code and are labeled with creations or uses of values and directed edges are potential program control flows (or some equivalent representation of the source code). Then assembler (or intermediate code) should be generated to implement the semantics required by the graph. If two sets of source code have equivalent graphs, the compiler should generate equivalent assembly (or intermediate code) for them (up to some reasonable ability to process complicated graphs) regardless of whether definitions in nested scopes were used or not.

Comment: Why do the compilers not try to reduce the stack depth in situations such as my example? Could it not reduce execution time in a large function?

Comment: @JasperNielsen: MSVC does do this optimization: https://godbolt.org/z/f9M8Kj.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Are `/Os` and `/Ot` not requesting any optimizations but just requesting that, if optimizations are required, that speed or time, respectively, be preferred? That would explain why the code is bad with `/Os` or `/Ot` but not with `/O2`.

Comment: @JasperNielsen: In fact, even adding `foo(&y)` and `foo(&z)` calls in each branch of the `if`, and making `x` not a compile-time constant, https://godbolt.org/z/sGdfKz, we do see MSVC 19.14 using the same stack slot for `y` and `z` (note `z$1=48` and `y$2=48` assemble-time constant offsets from RSP), exactly as the last paragraph of this answer suggests a good compiler should.  It seems to have just combined them into one variable who's value is determined by a branch.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: IDK, `-Ot` makes the same asm as no options (debug mode).  But strangely for Godbolt's MSVC under WINE, that asm doesn't make RBP a frame pointer so it's not full debug mode maybe?  Sounds like the OP needs to check the MSVC manual if they want to use options other than a standard `-O2` or `-Ox`.